# delete some tags from html document with c#

Tags: c#, html

I have a html document and I want to delete all the divs of certain class (with all the content). What is the simplest way to do it?

Thank you for your help.

**UPDATED:**

I tried out Html Agility Pack as you adviced, but I failed to reach the aim.
I have the following code

```
        static void Main()
        {
            HtmlDocument document = new HtmlDocument();
            document.Load(FileName);
            HtmlNode node = document.DocumentNode;
            HandleNode(node);
        }
```

```
    private static void HandleNode(HtmlNode node)
    {
        while (node != null)
        {
            if (node.Name == "div")
            {
                var attribute = node.Attributes.Where(x => x.Name == "class" && x.Value == "NavContent");
                if (attribute.Any())
                    node.Remove();
            }
            foreach (var childNode in node.ChildNodes)
            {
                HandleNode(childNode);
            }
        }

    }
```

But it doesn't do want I want. The recursion never ends and the node name is always comment.
Here's the htmp-document I'm trying to parse: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/work
Is there a good example how to work with Html Agility Pack?
What's wrong with this piece of code?

Comment: Do you want to delete the divs and their contents?

Comment: Your update should have been a separate question. Keeps things organized.

Comment: I managed to make it work as I want.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It depends on [how complex your HTML is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454), but you will probably need the [Agility Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack) library.

#### Re the Update:

HandleNode() contains a `while(node != null)` loop but never assigns to node. I would change that to an `if(...)` to start with.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 2):

To solve your problem, you can use LINQ:

```
foreach(var node in doc.DocumentNode
            .Descendants("div")
            .Where(d => d.GetAttributeValue("class", "").IndexOf("NavContent") >= 0)
            .ToArray())
    node.Remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually, I solve this kind of issue via File I/O and RegEx (which is not advised at all to deal with xml/html documents, as the commentators dutifully noted).

That said, if you want to do it properly, I'm pretty sure there's a DOM object in C#.

[This one](http://www.codeplex.com/wikipage?ProjectName=htmlagilitypack) seems to support XPath request, which is pretty handy.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: The div might have embedded divs. So how will you understand where the div ends?

Comment: Indeed, that's why I talked about a proper way to do such things (like Agility pack)